# Consulta en mysql en php no trae todos los resultados

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, union

Hola Gente tengo esa consulta en mysql

```
SELECT * FROM novedad N JOIN empleados E ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado
JOIN area A ON E.area_id=A.id_area WHERE N.id_empleado='4'
```

Eso me trae todas las novedades del empleado con el ID 4, pero a la hora de consultar con php me trae un solo un resultado, el primero.

Aca les dejo mi consulta.

```
$base = "SELECT * FROM novedad N JOIN empleados E ON N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado JOIN area A ON 
E.area_id=A.id_area WHERE N.id_empleado='$id_empleado'";
```

Eso en teoría debería traer todas las novedades del empleado con el ID 4 y trae solo una novedad la primera que se cargo.

Alguien me podría ayudar con eso?

Muchas Gracias

Como siempre muy atentos todos.

Comment: Aqui lo mas imortante es ver como ejecutas la consulta en php

Comment: Al parecer son 3 tablas, verdad.

Comment: Si, son tres tablas, pero quiero que traiga todas las novedades tabla N del empelado con id 4 y cuando ejeciuto en mysql me lo trae pero en la consulta php no, solo trae el primero que se cargo.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que estructurar el sql para que lo puedas interpretar mejor.
Si son 3 tablas según vi: (empleados, novedad, area)
Si es así tu $base sería:

```
$base = "SELECT * FROM novedad 
INNER JOIN empleados
ON novedad.empleado_id = empleados.id_empleado
INNER JOIN area
ON empleados.area_id = area.id_area
WHERE empleados.id_empleado = '$id_empleado'"
```

Ahí ya se estructura el INNER JOIN que intentas hacer.
saludos...

Comment: NO termino de entender ¿qué cambio aplicaste a la consulta?

Comment: Ese me salta error incluso en workbench

Comment: comparte el script de la data_base, bueno, solo el de las 3 tablas...

Comment: dices que salta error. Puede ser que no estes poniendo la consulta bien. Es un ejemplo, ya tu lo empleas de acuerdo a tus requerimientos. Ademas si son 3 tablas esa es la estructura. Al final despues del = coloca el numero 4

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces realción entre dos tablas asegurate de diferenciar los id.

Ejemplo teniendo en cuenta tu pregunta:

Tabla novedades

```
id_n | id_empleado | novedades
-----------------------------
1    | 2           | Empleo 1
2    | 1           | Empleo 2
3    | 4           | Empleo 3
4    | 4           | Empleo 4
```

Tabla empleados

```
id_e | nombre
--------------
1    | Pablo
2    | Miguel
3    | Lucas
4    | Pedro
```

Suponiendo que tenemos el id del usuario podemos hacer la consulta

```
<?php

$usuario = 4;

$base = "SELECT * FROM novedades INNER JOIN empleados ON usuario.id_e = empleados.id_empleado WHERE id_e = '".$usuario."'";

// 

while($row = $base->fetch()){
    echo $row['novedades'].'<br>';
}

// respuesta: Empleo 3, Empleo 4
?>
```

Como puedes ver, en el bucle te lista las novedades del usario con `ID 4`.

Este ejemplo es en base a la consulta que has hecho.